# Why HAProxy tcp-request content do-resolve is not working

Tags: dns, docker, tcp, haproxy, consul

i am using a combination of HAProxy (docker image v2.3.2) and Hashicorp Consul (v1.9.1) to access my VMs behind haproxy using SSH (i followed https://www.haproxy.com/fr/blog/route-ssh-connections-with-haproxy/)

1. My VMs are registered in consul
2. I use the dns service of consul which listens on 53/tcp and 53/udp port to map the node (vm) name to it's ip address

```
# the following command works just fine (it gives the ip address of registered node)
dig @<consul_server_ip> -p 53 <node_name>.node.<mydomain> +noall +answer
```

3. I started the haproxy container attached the host network with the following haproxy.cfg file

```
global
  log stdout format raw local0

defaults
  log global
  timeout client 60s
  timeout server 20s
  timeout connect 20s

resolvers consul
  accepted_payload_size 8192
  nameserver dns1 <consul_server_ip>:53
  resolve_retries      3
  timeout resolve      1s
  timeout retry        1s
  hold other           30s
  hold refused         30s
  hold nx              30s
  hold timeout         30s
  hold valid           10s
  hold obsolete        30s

frontend fe_ssh
  bind *:2222 ssl crt <path/to/ssl.pem>
  mode tcp
  log-format "%ci:%cp [%t] %ft %b/%s %Tw/%Tc/%Tt %B %ts %ac/%fc/%bc/%sc/%rc %sq/%bq dstName:%[var(sess.dstName)] dstIP:%[var(sess.dstIP)]"
  tcp-request content do-resolve(sess.dstIP,consul,ipv4) ssl_fc_sni
  tcp-request content set-var(sess.dstName) ssl_fc_sni
  default_backend be_ssh-servers

backend be_ssh-servers
  mode tcp
  tcp-request content set-dst var(sess.dstIP)
  server ssh-srv 0.0.0.0:22
```

Now when i try to connect to one of my VMs behind the haproxy with the command

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/<mynode-priv-key.pem> -o ProxyCommand="openssl s_client -quiet -connect haproxy.mydomain:2222 -servername <node_name>.node.<mydomain>" <user>@<node_name>.node.<mydomain>
```

the ssh command tries to connect to the VM where the haproxy is running (haproxy.mydomain) and not the specified one with

```
-servername <node_name>.node.<mydomain>
```

and haproxy log gives me this

```
source_ip:port [date/time] fe_ssh~ be_ssh-servers/ssh-srv 60/1/3546 3037 -- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 dstName:<node_name>.node.<mydomain> dstIP:-
```

so as you see in the log haproxy printed the correct name of my node

```
dstName=<node_name>.node.<mydomain>
```

and not the of haproxy.mydomain (VM where haproxy is running) but,

THERE IS NO ip (dstIP) address associated to my vm (<node_name>.node. ) that i am trying to connect to using SSH due the resolver issue i think

any help and ideas how to debug this issue (as i am new to haproxy and consul) will be appreciated. thanks all in advance.

NB: i already used the consul-template to get what i want but i wanna make it work without using it

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this to your configuration

```
tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
```

in the fronted part of your configuration.

Had the same issue and asked the same question:
https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/do-resolve-not-working/6504